# SSRS Dateformat Max Date issue

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, datetime-format

I am getting a weird issue in SSRS. Say I have a dataset with the record `createdon` date as shown below.

```
createdon
12/7/2018 5:11 PM
12/11/2018 6:10 PM
12/12/2018 8:07 PM
12/14/2018 1:24 PM
12/14/2018 2:10 PM
12/14/2018 4:24 PM
12/4/2018 9:57 PM
12/6/2018 4:25 PM
12/6/2018 4:30 PM
```

How can I get the Max(creation) date?  If I do max, I am getting 12/7/2018 5:11 PM instead of 12/14/2018 4:24 PM.

Comment: What datatype is your `createdon` column? I am guessing `varchar`, so `max(convert(datetime,createdon))` may give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Max(CDate(Fields!Createdon.Value))
```